Unable to resolve - Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
I've been encountering this issue for a while now. I've tried various solutions, such as toggling between offline and online modes in Gradle, adding
maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") } in the project build.gradle, and more, but I still can't resolve the error.
Note: My project is primarily in Java, but I recently added Kotlin code due to the requirements of the Supabase Database SDK. That's why you may encounter Kotlin and Groovy in the project
Error:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Project build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath libs.google.services
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
}

App build.gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.indiedev91.looksmaxeai_bebetterversion'
    compileSdk 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.indiedev91.looksmaxeai_bebetterversion"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 35
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"your_production_api_key\""
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"your_production_api_key\""
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.activity
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.firebase.auth
    implementation libs.firebase.firestore
    implementation libs.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools
    implementation libs.firebase.storage
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core

    def camerax_version = "1.3.0"
    implementation libs.camera.core
    implementation libs.camera.camera2
    implementation libs.camera.lifecycle
    implementation libs.camera.view
    implementation libs.concurrent.futures.ktx
    implementation libs.guava
    // Loading animations
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'

    // Circle Image View
    implementation libs.circleimageview

    implementation libs.work.runtime

    //Google Credential Manager
    implementation libs.credentials
    implementation libs.credentials.play.services.auth.v150beta01
    implementation libs.googleid.v111

    implementation libs.core.ktx
    implementation libs.kotlin.stdlib
    implementation(libs.bom)
    implementation("io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:postgrest-kt")
    implementation("io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:gotrue-kt")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:3.0.1")



}

settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
  
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

rootProject.name = "LooksMaxE AI - Be Better Version"
include ':app'

Update:- As requested im sharing the libs.versions.toml file
libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.3.0"
bom = "3.0.1"
cameraCore = "1.3.0"
circleimageview = "3.1.0"
concurrentFuturesKtx = "1.2.0"
coreKtx = "1.15.0"
credentials = "1.5.0-beta01"
credentialsPlayServicesAuth = "1.3.0"
credentialsPlayServicesAuthVersion = "1.5.0-beta01"
emojislider = "0.3.2"
googleid = "1.3.0"
googleidVersion = "1.1.1"
guava = "29.0-android"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
kotlinStdlib = "2.0.21"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.8.0"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
googleServices = "4.4.2"
firebaseAuth = "23.1.0"
firebaseFirestore = "25.1.1"
firebaseCrashlyticsBuildtools = "3.0.2"
firebaseStorage = "21.0.1"
workRuntime = "2.10.0"

[libraries]
bom = { module = "io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:bom", version.ref = "bom" }
camera-camera2 = { module = "androidx.camera:camera-camera2", version.ref = "cameraCore" }
camera-core = { module = "androidx.camera:camera-core", version.ref = "cameraCore" }
camera-lifecycle = { module = "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle", version.ref = "cameraCore" }
camera-view = { module = "androidx.camera:camera-view", version.ref = "cameraCore" }
circleimageview = { module = "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview", version.ref = "circleimageview" }
concurrent-futures-ktx = { module = "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures-ktx", version.ref = "concurrentFuturesKtx" }
core-ktx = { module = "androidx.core:core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
credentials = { module = "androidx.credentials:credentials", version.ref = "credentials" }
credentials-play-services-auth = { module = "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth", version.ref = "credentialsPlayServicesAuth" }
credentials-play-services-auth-v150beta01 = { module = "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth", version.ref = "credentialsPlayServicesAuthVersion" }
emojislider = { module = "com.bernaferrari.emojislider:emojislider", version.ref = "emojislider" }
googleid = { module = "com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid", version.ref = "googleid" }
googleid-v111 = { module = "com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid", version.ref = "googleidVersion" }
guava = { module = "com.google.guava:guava", version.ref = "guava" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
kotlin-stdlib = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", version.ref = "kotlinStdlib" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
google-services = { group = "com.google.gms", name = "google-services", version.ref = "googleServices" }
firebase-auth = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-auth", version.ref = "firebaseAuth" }
firebase-firestore = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-firestore", version.ref = "firebaseFirestore" }
firebase-crashlytics-buildtools = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-crashlytics-buildtools", version.ref = "firebaseCrashlyticsBuildtools" }
firebase-storage = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-storage", version.ref = "firebaseStorage" }
work-runtime = { module = "androidx.work:work-runtime", version.ref = "workRuntime" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }


Please also provide your version catalog.

What u mean by catalog ?.

The place where you define what libs.appcompat is, for example. It's the file libs.versions.toml in your gradle folder. You should familiarize yourself with the version catalog. A good place to start would be here: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs -- But for now we just need that file's content as it is.

can u explain why is this needed to resolve the issue ??

It's needed so we can actually build it ourselves. Without the version catalog the dependencies cannot be resolved. If the dependencies are not relevant to reproduce the issue you can also just remove them from the question. In that case please don't forget to remove libs.google.services as well. The goal is to provide a [mre].

im already having that file , i just check , i have updated the code , please check

I see two main issues with your build files:

The Supabase BOM needs to be implemented as platform. Replace
implementation(libs.bom)

with
implementation(platform(libs.bom))

You might also want to consider renaming bom to supabase-bom or something along the lines. There are many BOMs out there. This one is the BOM for Supabase.

io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:gotrue-kt doesn't exist. From the project page:

Warning This repository is archived. Use supabase-kt instead to use Supabase in your Kotlin projects.

Since you use postgrest-kt which already transitively uses supabase-kt you can simply remove this line:
implementation("io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:gotrue-kt")



